# Adding a button, with onclick function, via javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I'm struggling to find the correct syntax for adding a button via javascript/jquery that has a function attached.

Right now I am trying:

```
list.append("<button onclick='getFeed('http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/PA2/3dayforecast.rss, showFeedResults')'>ButtonTest</button>");
```

But it returns:

```
<button onclick="getFeed(" http:="" open.live.bbc.co.uk="" weather="" feeds="" en="" pa2="" 3dayforecast.rss,="" showfeedresults')'="">ButtonTest</button>
```

Essentially, I want to be able to create

```
<button onclick="getFeed('http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/B1/3dayforecast.rss', showFeedResults)" class="ui-btn-hidden">
```

In javascript, But can't figure out how..`

And I seem to be having trouble wrapping my head around creating html elements that use both single and double qoutation marks.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following answers are better solution, but your problem can be solved by using escaped quote like this var text = "aaa\"bb";

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Append a button with click event listener assigned

Using pure JavaScript

```js
const NewEL = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Use like:
const EL_btn = NewEL("button", {
  textContent: "Test button",
  onclick() { console.log(this); /* getFeed etc... */ },
});

document.body.append(EL_btn);
```

Or using the **jQuery** library

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
list.append("<button>ButtonTest</button>");

list.on("click", "button", function(){
    getFeed('http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/PA2/3dayforecast.rss, showFeedResults');
});
```

For dynamically generated elements use `.on()` method like above.

Comment: Might want to make it more definitive that `on` should only be called once, outside of this code/loop

Comment: @roXon, What tells you that there's a single button in that list? You should explain what's the difference between attaching the handler on the parent using a delagating approach and attach the handler directly on the element. Also, `on` is not only for dynamically created elements, but is a best practice all the time... `onclick=""` should not be used at all.

Comment: @plalx "is a best practice all the time" - that's not true. There are plenty of arguments either way.

Comment: @plalx to add to your comment - adding an ID to the button and referencing to that ID inside the `.on` *element delegation* should be best, but I think that would be quite easy for the OP to figure that out. If you do that job, some things are sometimes self explanatory. If you know the job. Still waiting for an OP comment to see how to improve for his exact needs. (If needed).

Comment: @Ian, do you have an example where `onclick=""` is prefered?

Answer (score 6):

While I think using an [`on`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16177477/229044) handler on the entire list is better, it's also perfectly acceptable to just bind events to disconnected DOM elements before adding them to the DOM:

```
button = $("<button>Button Test</button>");

button.click(function () {
  getFeed('http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/PA2/3dayforecast.rss, showFeedResults');
});

list.append(button);
```

Comment: While it's acceptable, it doesn't mean it should be suggested (not saying **this** should or shouldn't be suggested, but it makes most sense to use event delegation here). And it would make more sense if you declared the handler function once and referenced it, and used `button.on("click", handler);`, otherwise, a new anonymous function is created/referenced each time.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in vanilla javascript

```
<div id="something"></div>

var something = document.getElementById("something");
var button = document.createElement("button");

function doSomething() {
    alert("hi");
}

button.id = "myButton";
button.textContent = "Click me";
button.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

something.appendChild(button);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/uN8vw/)

Also, inline javascript: 
i.e. `<button onclick="getFeed()">`
is considered bad practice and can cause a number of unexpected issues.

Answer (score 0):

First create the element using the DOM APIs:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
```

Next, set its attributes:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {...});
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button Test'));
```

Finally, add it to the document:

```
someParentElement.appendChild(button);
```